# Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs', webpack.config.js cannot be found, npm ERR! Missing script: "eject"

Tags: next.js, node.js-fs

I'm trying to develop my first webapp with next.js. This is my first experience in webdev (I'm coming from a firmware engineering background).
I'm trying to set up an access to my mongodb database from my next.js app, but i get the error described below.

I don't understand because the app was correctly building before adding the mangodb management and the error seems to be related to a library that i didnt install in between, so it must have already been here.

Of course i'd really like a solution but if you can also explain what's all this about it'd be awesome. I have to admit it's pretty obscure to me

thanks

I have the following error when running npm run dev:

```
 ○ Compiling / ...
 ⨯ ./node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:5:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/mongodb-client-encryption/lib/index.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/client-side-encryption/client_encryption.js
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./lib/db.js
./pages/index.js
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Caching failed for pack: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/Users/camille/Documents/NextjsTraining/motsderobes/.next/cache/webpack/client-development-fallback/0.pack.gz_' -> '/Users/camille/Documents/NextjsTraining/motsderobes/.next/cache/webpack/client-development-fallback/0.pack.gz'
```

I already added the following to my package.json file :

```
"browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "os": false,
    "path": false
  }
```

I cannot find webpack.config.js where internet told me to add :

```
module.exports = function (webpackEnv) {
  // ...
  return {
   // ...
    resolve: {
      // ...
      fallback: {
        // ️️️ add this ️️️
        "fs": false,
        "os": false,
        "path": false,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: did you find any answers?